# Jumping Frogs (Frog Puzzle) using DFS

Tags: java

I have been trying to implement the Jumping Frogs puzzle (here is a good link to what I mean http://britton.disted.camosun.bc.ca/frog_puzzle.htm) in Java with the goal being to print out the steps from the beginning to the right ending (successfull solution).
I am using an Arraylist to write the nodes I have already visited and a stack to get back to parent nodes if necessary.
However, the program prints odd things, although the algorithm seems to be working fine...any ideas why is this happening and how can I fix this?

```
public class JumpingFrogs {

public static int indexOfZero(int arr[]){
    int index=0;
    for (int i=0; i <arr.length; i++){
        if (arr[i]==0) index = i;
    }
    return index;
}

public static int[] swap(int[] arr, int ind1, int ind2){
    int temp = arr[ind1];
    arr[ind1] = arr[ind2];
    arr[ind2] = temp;
    return arr;
}

public static int[] makeCopy(int[] arr){
    int[] copy = new int[arr.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < copy.length; i++){
        copy[i] = arr[i];
    }
    return copy;
}

public static boolean isContained(int[] arr, ArrayList arrayList){
    if(arrayList.isEmpty()) return false;
    for (Object arrayList1 : arrayList) {
        if (Arrays.equals(arr, (int[]) arrayList1)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.print("Input number of frogs on each side: ");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int frogNumber = input.nextInt();
    int[] root = new int[2*frogNumber + 1];
    int[] solution = new int[2*frogNumber + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < 2*frogNumber + 1; i++){
        if (i < frogNumber){
          root[i] = 1;  
          solution[i]=2;
        }
        else{
            if (i == frogNumber){
                root[i] = 0;
                solution[i] = 0;
            }
            else{
                root[i] = 2;
                solution[i] = 1;
            }
        }
    }

    Stack stack = new Stack();
    ArrayList visitedNodes = new ArrayList();
    stack.push(makeCopy(root));


    do{

        int i0=indexOfZero(root);
        if((i0 >= 2)&&(root[i0-2] == 1)&&(!isContained((swap(makeCopy(root), i0 - 2, i0)), visitedNodes))){
            swap(root, i0 - 2, i0); 
            stack.push(makeCopy(root));
            visitedNodes.add(makeCopy(root));    
            continue;
        }
        if((i0 >= 1)&&(root[i0-1] == 1)&&(!isContained((swap(makeCopy(root), i0 - 1, i0)), visitedNodes))){
            swap(root, i0 - 1, i0);
            stack.push(makeCopy(root));
            visitedNodes.add(makeCopy(root));
            continue;
        }
        if((i0 < root.length - 1)&&(root[i0+1] == 2)&&(!isContained((swap(makeCopy(root), i0+1, i0)), visitedNodes))){
            swap(root, i0 + 1, i0);
            stack.push(makeCopy(root));
            visitedNodes.add(makeCopy(root));
            continue;
        }
        if((i0 < root.length - 2)&&(root[i0+2] == 2)&&(!isContained((swap(makeCopy(root), i0+2, i0)), visitedNodes))){
            swap(root, i0 + 2, i0);
            stack.push(makeCopy(root));
            visitedNodes.add(makeCopy(root));
            continue;
        }

        stack.pop();
        root=(int[]) stack.peek();
    }
    while(!Arrays.equals(root, solution));

    Stack path = new Stack();
    while(!stack.empty()){
        path.push(stack.pop());
    }

    while(!path.empty()){
        int[] step = (int[]) path.pop();
        for (int p = 0; p < step.length; p++){
            System.out.print(step[p]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    System.out.println("The program has ended successfully!");



}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try clone *root* like,

```
do{
    proccessing
     .
     .
     .
     .
     .
     .         
    stack.pop();
    root=(int[]) stack.peek();
    //add
    root = root.clone();
  }
```